# Angularjs date picker mindate max date validation error messages

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

Using Angularjs with spring(java)

I have following Angularjs bootstrap datepicker. it shows error when field is empty i am trying to inplace mindate validation which is today's date. if user type min-date should display error msg.

I tried placing check like 'form.offerStartDate.$error.mindate' but there is no property for mindate in error object. any help appreciated.

```
<p class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="offerStartDate" class="form-control" ng-required="true" 
                    ng-class="{error: form.offerStartDate.$dirty && form.offerStartDate.$invalid}"  
                    datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy" ng-model="formData.offerStartDate"
                    is-open="startDateOpened" min-date="minDate"
                    datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                    date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
                    close-text="Close" /> <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event,'startDate')">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </p>
            </div>

            <div ng-show="form.offerStartDate.$dirty && form.offerStartDate.$invalid">
                    <small class="err-msg" ng-show="form.offerStartDate.$error.required">
                        Offer Start Date is required.
                    </small>
<small class="err-msg" ng-show="form.offerStartDate.$error.mindate">
                        Offer mindate is today's date.
                    </small>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `min-date` to `min` in `input`

It may be related with this issue:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2189